# Put TFS Team Project Offline

Tags: tfs

I migrated a Team Project to a different collection using Microsoft Team Foundation Server Integration Tools.

Now I would like to take the original project offline (but not delete). Anyone knows of a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698947/how-to-lock-obsolete-teamprojects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by removing all the users from the security groups of the original project.

Comment: Thanks, a simple and functional solution